# How to retain Colors in my Richtextbox even after Replacing

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have Richtexbox with some texts and markup tags, i color it based on the Tags to different colors in form load, coloring of texts/tags works fine,

Problem now is when i tried to replace some Text inside My RTFbox, after coloring, the Color seems to vanish everywhere,

I want to retain all the coloring's i did even after any kind of replacements/Editing's in richtextbox, kindly help

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the text during the replace, you also delete and formatting the text contained. The inserted text will default to whatever style is set for the area it's being inserted. If you want to retain the styling, you will have to get the current styling of the text and save it in memory, and then apply it to the new text you're inserting, something like this:

```
RichTextBox1.Select(0, 5)
Dim txtStyle As Font = RichTextBox1.SelectionFont
```

Then you can apply txtStyle to whatever text you're inserting/replacing the old stuff with

Comment: how to reapply the TxtStyle after replacement?

Comment: The same way as shown above, the only difference is the second line is used in reverse. Select the text first, and then set the selection's font to the font you just retrieved like "RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = txtStyle"